# How to open ViewController From AppDelegate With NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

i want to open ViewController From AppDelegate when i get notification from OneSignal, and its working but the problem is when ViewController opened there is not toolbar , how can i open it with toolbar ? i am using embed in Navigation Controller.

this is the code in AppDelegate to open ViewController

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let instantiateRedViewController : ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as! ViewController
                instantiateRedViewController.receivedURL = additionalData["openURL"] as! String?
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                self.window?.rootViewController = instantiateRedViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) When you say "toolbar" do you mean "navigation bar"? (Hint: They are totally different things.)

(2) There is no navigation controller in your code, so naturally no navigation bar appears. Where is this "embed in Navigation Controller"? If it's in the storyboard, then you are instantiating the wrong view controller in the 2nd line of your code; you need to instantiate the navigation controller.

Comment: yes , i mean "navigation bar" , when i open viewcontroller from storyboard then "navigation bar" appears but from appdelegate  its not

Comment: Yup, well, my answer tells you exactly why.

Comment: please can you tell me how to instantiate the navigation controller ? sorry , i am very new to Xcode, please if you can

Comment: Exactly the same way you are doing: by its identifier.

Comment: let instantiateRedViewController : ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstscreen") as! UINavigationController ,, Like This ?  first screen is StoryBoard Id of navigation controller, but i dont have any file connected with it

Comment: I don't know what "file connected with it" means. If you instantiate the navigation controller (as you just said) and make that your window's root view controller, you will see the navigation bar. Try it and see.

Comment: thanks for help , it works , but one more question there is not back button when i open another otherViewController rather than ViewController . is is possible ?

Comment: That seems to me to be a completely different question. Please do not piggy back on the existing question. If the first question is answered satisfactorily, the way to ask a new question is to ask a new question (Ask Question button is at the top right of this page).